# 2 years old Zenfone 5, how to control battery use?

Tags: battery, asus-zenfone-5

Sorry for asking about such an overdone subject.

Question is, I have a (as of now) 2 years old **Zenfone 5**.
Android 4.4.2, ZenUI, not rooted (yet), Energy Management off, stock charger.

Configurations include minimal brightness, only antenna is constantly on, and I have touch feedback from Dev Config on.

For the last 3 months, my battery seems less able to take on Wi-Fi, and Google's apps specifically.
For a measure, I already had my battery last little less than 40h, by not using any Internet whatsoever. Now, I start using Wi-Fi and it drops at a rate of 0.3% per min. I remember a time I could use it the same way, and it'd last at least two hours more than now.

Apps recently downloaded include **Piano Tiles 2**, **Avast** and **Malwarebytes**, both of the latter I already uninstalled. Piano Tiles 2 force-stopped.

As of posting this question, I've force-stopped most non-crucial apps beyond aforementioned and turned Energy Manag. back on, to see if anything change. I'll report back any improvement.

Thanks in advance!